# Problemas de biblioteca no servidor JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, glassfish

Estou com um problema meio estranho, minha aplicação funciona perfeitamente no NetBeans porém ao subir para o servidor o mesmo esta dando erro, diz que não encontra algumas bibliotecas. Achei muito estranho tendo em vista que todas as bibliotecas estão no *classpath* e que no Glassfish do Jboss inicia normalmente. Testei também no Tomcat e funcionou.

Alguém sabe me dizer o que pode ser?

O log:

```
18:01:01,185 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-6) WELD-001208 Warning when validating vfs:/e:/Program Files/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/ProjetoX.war/WEB-INF/lib/vraptor-4.2.0-RC3.jar/META-INF/beans.xml@5 against xsd. schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
18:01:02,196 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-6) WELD-001208 Warning when validating vfs:/e:/Program Files/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/ProjetoX.war/WEB-INF/lib/vraptor-4.2.0-RC3.jar/META-INF/beans.xml@7 against xsd. schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
18:01:03,205 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-6) WELD-001208 Warning when validating vfs:/e:/Program Files/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/ProjetoX.war/WEB-INF/lib/vraptor-4.2.0-RC3.jar/META-INF/beans.xml@8 against xsd. schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
18:01:04,211 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-6) WELD-001208 Warning when validating vfs:/e:/Program Files/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/ProjetoX.war/WEB-INF/lib/vraptor-4.2.0-RC3.jar/META-INF/beans.xml@9 against xsd. schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
18:01:05,210 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-6) WELD-001208 Warning when validating vfs:/e:/Program Files/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/ProjetoX.war/WEB-INF/lib/vraptor-4.2.0-RC3.jar/META-INF/beans.xml@12 against xsd. schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
18:01:06,212 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-6) WELD-001208 Warning when validating vfs:/e:/Program Files/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/ProjetoX.war/WEB-INF/lib/vraptor-4.2.0-RC3.jar/META-INF/beans.xml@13 against xsd. schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
18:01:07,220 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-6) WELD-001208 Warning when validating vfs:/e:/Program Files/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/ProjetoX.war/WEB-INF/lib/vraptor-4.2.0-RC3.jar/META-INF/beans.xml@16 against xsd. schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
18:01:08,223 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-6) WELD-001208 Warning when validating vfs:/e:/Program Files/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/ProjetoX.war/WEB-INF/lib/vraptor-4.2.0-RC3.jar/META-INF/beans.xml@17 against xsd. schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
18:01:09,221 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-6) WELD-001208 Warning when validating vfs:/e:/Program Files/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/ProjetoX.war/WEB-INF/lib/vraptor-4.2.0-RC3.jar/META-INF/beans.xml@20 against xsd. schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
18:01:10,223 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-6) WELD-001208 Warning when validating vfs:/e:/Program Files/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/ProjetoX.war/WEB-INF/lib/vraptor-4.2.0-RC3.jar/META-INF/beans.xml@21 against xsd. schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
18:01:11,221 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-6) WELD-001208 Warning when validating vfs:/e:/Program Files/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/ProjetoX.war/WEB-INF/lib/vraptor-4.2.0-RC3.jar/META-INF/beans.xml@24 against xsd. schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
18:01:12,240 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-6) WELD-001208 Warning when validating vfs:/e:/Program Files/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/ProjetoX.war/WEB-INF/lib/vraptor-4.2.0-RC3.jar/META-INF/beans.xml@25 against xsd. schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
18:01:13,254 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-6) WELD-001208 Warning when validating vfs:/e:/Program Files/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/ProjetoX.war/WEB-INF/beans.xml@5 against xsd. schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
18:01:14,060 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment ProjetoX.war
18:01:14,132 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS016006: Could not load portable extension class org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidationExtension: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.loadExtension(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:117) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.loadAttachments(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:100) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.deploy(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:86) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.Configuration.getBootstrapConfiguration()Ljavax/validation/BootstrapConfiguration;
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidationExtension.<init>(ValidationExtension.java:120) [hibernate-validator-cdi-5.1.1.Final.jar:5.1.1.Final]
    ... 13 more

18:01:14,198 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (version 4.0)
18:01:14,199 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: ProjetoX.war
18:01:14,212 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS016008: Starting weld service for deployment ProjetoX.war
18:01:14,383 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-2) Failed to define class br.com.caelum.vraptor.view.LinkToHandler in Module "deployment.ProjetoX.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link br/com/caelum/vraptor/view/LinkToHandler (Module "deployment.ProjetoX.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:396)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2397) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1806) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$4.work(SecureReflections.java:102) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$4.work(SecureReflections.java:99) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAndWrap(SecureReflectionAccess.java:63) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.getDeclaredFields(SecureReflections.java:99) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.<init>(WeldClassImpl.java:153) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.of(WeldClassImpl.java:118) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:49) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:40) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:355)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:184)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:153)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:69)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:393)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:149) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:86) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClasses(BeanDeployer.java:115) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:171) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:336) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:82) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ForwardingMap
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.ForwardingMap from [Module "deployment.ProjetoX.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 42 more

18:01:14,428 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.ClassLoading] (MSC service thread 1-2) WELD-000119 Not generating any bean definitions from br.com.caelum.vraptor.view.LinkToHandler$1 because of underlying class loading error
18:01:14,435 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.ClassLoading] (MSC service thread 1-2) catching: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error loading class br.com.caelum.vraptor.view.LinkToHandler$1
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:152) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:86) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClasses(BeanDeployer.java:115) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:171) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:336) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:82) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lbr/com/caelum/vraptor/view/LinkToHandler;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2397) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1806) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$4.work(SecureReflections.java:102) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$4.work(SecureReflections.java:99) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAndWrap(SecureReflectionAccess.java:63) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.getDeclaredFields(SecureReflections.java:99) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.<init>(WeldClassImpl.java:153) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.of(WeldClassImpl.java:118) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:49) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:40) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:355)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:184)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:153)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:69)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:393)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:149) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.com.caelum.vraptor.view.LinkToHandler from [Module "deployment.ProjetoX.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 29 more

18:01:14,497 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.ClassLoading] (MSC service thread 1-2) WELD-000119 Not generating any bean definitions from br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.CustomAcceptsVerifier because of underlying class loading error
18:01:14,497 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.ClassLoading] (MSC service thread 1-2) catching: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error loading class br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.CustomAcceptsVerifier
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:152) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:86) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClasses(BeanDeployer.java:115) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:171) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:336) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:82) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Predicate
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2397) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1806) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$4.work(SecureReflections.java:102) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$4.work(SecureReflections.java:99) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAndWrap(SecureReflectionAccess.java:63) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.getDeclaredFields(SecureReflections.java:99) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.<init>(WeldClassImpl.java:153) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.of(WeldClassImpl.java:118) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:49) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:40) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:355)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:184)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:153)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:69)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:393)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:149) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Predicate from [Module "deployment.ProjetoX.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 29 more

18:01:14,606 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-2) Failed to define class br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.WithAnnotationAcceptor$1 in Module "deployment.ProjetoX.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link br/com/caelum/vraptor/interceptor/WithAnnotationAcceptor$1 (Module "deployment.ProjetoX.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:396)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldModuleResourceLoader.classForName(WeldModuleResourceLoader.java:68) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:77) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClasses(BeanDeployer.java:115) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:171) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:336) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:82) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Predicate
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Predicate from [Module "deployment.ProjetoX.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: Você pode adicionar o seu `classpath`?

Comment: cdi-api-1.1.jar
classmate-1.1.0.jar
el-api-2.2.jar
gson-2.2.4.jar
hibernate-validator-5.1.1.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-cdi-5.1.1.Final.jar
iogi-1.0.0.jar
javaee-web-api-7.0.jar
javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
javax.ejb-api-3.2.jar
javax.inject-1.jar
javax.interceptor-api-1.2.jar
javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar
jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Alpha1.jar
jboss-classfilewriter-1.0.4.Final.jar
jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Alpha1.jar
jboss-interceptors-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Alpha3.jar

Comment: jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
mirror-1.6.1.jar
paranamer-2.7.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar
sqljdbc4.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
vraptor-4.2.0-RC3.jar
xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar
xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
xstream-1.4.7.jar
joda-time-2.4-javadoc.jar
joda-time-2.4-sources.jar
joda-time-2.4.jar

Comment: essas são as bibliotecas do meu projeto, infelizmente o site não pega as quebras de linha